# Keystore File Tampered With PhoneGap Build (Password Error)

Tags: android, phonegap-build, keystore, phonegap, signing

So I built a PhoneGap app in May, uploading updated builds on Google Play every week or so. This last time I did it, however, it claimed that my password was incorrect. I've done everything I can think of, but I'm missing something.

**The History:**

- Built the .jks in May and (likely cut) and pasted it to the directory where I keep the zip file. (It's got 10,000 days on it, so no problem there.)
- Renamed the .jks to a .keystore extension.
- Routinely used the keystore in PhoneGap Build with the correct certificate password and keystore password when updating the app's code and re-signing the app.
- Tonight, I received an error stating that the password was incorrect. The keystore has remained unchanged since May.

**Attempted Solutions**

- I deleted and reloaded the keystore from PhoneGap build with both (of two) possible aliases, and tried to unlock those files. No dice.
- I went back to the keytool from the command prompt and tried to open it there with the same password, and got this back:

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or
>   password was incorrect java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered
>   with, or password was incorrect
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification
>   failed

- Again, I know the password, so I tried renaming it back to the .jks extension. Same result. No dice.
- I'm left to conclude that my .keystore was tampered with. Beyond changing the extension from .jks to .keystore, I don't know how it could have been.

**Questions**

1. **What methods are available for me to recover this .keystore file to its original functionality?** Brute force is a bad option only because the original password is over 20 characters long.
2. **How can I view a list of keystores present my Java keytool?**
3. **Is there a way to transfer to a different keystore without having to republish the app in Google Play from scratch?** There aren't a ton of users on it yet, but I don't want to have to do this every three months.

Comment: Have you created it on android studio?

Comment: No, I built it in Visual Studio Code using PhoneGap.

Comment: And no, I built the `keystore` in Java's Keytool from the Command Prompt.